# Determine assembly that contains a class from the classname (not an instance of a type)

Tags: c#

I am trying to determine which assembly contains a particular class.  I do NOT want to create an instance of a type in that assembly, but want something like this

```
namespace SomeAssembly
{
   class SomeClass
    {
    }
}
```

..and In client code I want:

```
Assembly containingAssembly = GetContainingAssembly(SomeClass)
```

Comment: Please don't put tags like "C#" in the title. Leave them in the tags.

Answer (score 6):

If you have the `System.Type` instance (eg, `typeof(SomeType)`), you can check the `Assembly` property.

If you only have a string, you can loop through `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` calling `assembly.GetType(typeName)` until you find the assembly that contains the type.  (`typeName` *must* include the full namespace)
Note that this will be extremely slow.

If the assembly has not been loaded, you can give up; it's impossible.  (Unless you can load the assembly yourself)

Answer (score 4):

Simple:

```
typeof(SomeClass).Assembly;
```

If you want to make it a function:

```
public static Assembly GetContainingAssembly<T>()
{
    return typeof(T).Assembly;
}
```

Then Execute like this:

```
Assembly containingAssembly = GetContainingAssembly<SomeClass>();
```

For any instance object it's pretty simple to:

```
obj something;

something.GetType().Assembly;
```